# Two textviews in same line where second one starts from beginning for second and other lines

Tags: java, android, textview

I need to implement a structure where two text views lie side by side and whenever second textview get to the second line, it should start under the first text view like in Instagram.

[image]

Comment: look here: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/text/spans#java

Comment: thanks, this solved my problem @Oktawian